# What happened to ( aristotelian) substantial forms in cartesian ontology? On which ground ( metaphysical or physical) are they rejected?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, descartes

- In aristotelian philosophy, there are no bare particulars ( contrary to what is the case in Plato, according to P.V. Spade) but internally structured ( substantial) particulars in which 2 "parts"/aspects   can be distinguished ( though not separated) : matter and form.

Form is what makes a particular the kind of entity it is ; it is an embodied essence.

- In cartesian ontology , the notion of substantial form disappears totally in the case of ordinary physical bodies ( the case of the human body being special).

However, Descartes does not seem to give much explanations as to the reasons why " substantial forms" become useless in his ontology. And commentators concentrate on Descartes strategy as to the reception of his doctrine ( strategy consisting , as he writes to his disciple Regis, in not attacking " substantial forms" directly and overtly) ; but are rather silent as to the reasons why substantial forms disappear.

- One explanation I see is the following , though I can't provide textual evidence for it :

> (1) Descartes rejects natural kinds ( for him, all bodies - be they
>   "wax"  " stone" , " diamond", " star"  - though appearing distinct in
>   essence at the level of perception -  are parts of the same thing,
>   namely matter or extended substance; they all share the same essence -
>   being extended).
>
> (2) The only function of " substantial form" is to explain natural
>   kind membership .
>
> (3) So, without natural kinds, substantial forms become useless.

- Is this argument correct? It seems to me a bit general and abstract. It could also be suspected of begging the question ( how can Descartes know there are no natural kinds without first knowing there are no substantial forms?)

***Are there more precise reasons, linked to Descartes physical theory, for rejecting substantial forms?***

***What makes substantial forms in principle incompatible with (Descartes) new physics?***

***Is there a reference in which this question is dealt with precisely?***

Comment: See specialized literature on the subject: Helen Hattab, [Descartes on Forms and Mechanisms (Cambridge UP, 2009)](https://books.google.it/books?id=2JEbXH88qAUC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: First, a clarification. Substantial forms are not the same as essences of natural kinds, they are forms with independent causal powers, like souls. And the answer is, in a nutshell, that they were superseded by mechanism as a mode of explanation, and Descartes was a mechanist like most 17th century scientists. See [Was there a “mechanist” program of early rationalists, like Descartes and Leibniz?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/68873/9148) for details.

Comment: Thanks for these accurate references.